# It keeps displaying incorrect module name and number, how can it be fixed?

Tags: php, html

Below I have a php script where it displays a "Course" drop down menu and a "Module" Drop down menu. What is suppose to happen is the user first selects a course from the "Course" drop down menu and then a list of Modules which belongs to the selected course will appear in the "Modules" drop down menu. Below is the code for this:

```
create_session.php  



$sql = "SELECT CourseId, CourseNo, CourseName FROM Course"; 

$sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

$sqlstmt->execute(); 

$sqlstmt->bind_result($dbCourseId, $dbCourseNo, $dbCourseName);

$courses = array(); // easier if you don't use generic names for data 

$courseHTML = "";  
$courseHTML .= '<select name="courses" id="coursesDrop">'.PHP_EOL; 
$courseHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  

while($sqlstmt->fetch()) 
{ 
    $courseno = $dbCourseNo;
    $course = $dbCourseId;
    $coursename = $dbCourseName; 
    $courseHTML .= "<option value='".$course."'>" . $courseno . " - " . $coursename . "</option>".PHP_EOL;  
} 

$courseHTML .= '</select>'; 

?>


<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Course: <?php echo $courseHTML; ?>
                <input id="courseSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $submittedCourseId = $_POST['courses'];

    $query = "SELECT cm.CourseId, cm.ModuleId, c.CourseNo, m.ModuleNo,
            c.CourseName,
            m.ModuleName
            FROM Course c
            INNER JOIN Course_Module cm ON c.CourseId = cm.CourseId
            JOIN Module m ON cm.ModuleId = m.ModuleId
            WHERE
            (c.CourseId = ?)
            ORDER BY c.CourseName, m.ModuleId";

    $qrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);

    // You only need to call bind_param once
    $qrystmt->bind_param("s",$submittedCourseId);
    // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)

    $qrystmt->execute(); 

    $qrystmt->bind_result($dbCourseId,$dbModuleId,$dbCourseNo,$dbModuleNo,$dbCourseName,$dbModuleName);

    $qrystmt->store_result();

    $num = $qrystmt->num_rows();

    if($num ==0){
        echo "<p style='color: red'>Please Select a Course</p>";
    } else { 

        $dataArray = array();

        while ( $qrystmt->fetch() ) { 
            // data array
            $dataArray[$dbCourseId]['CourseName'] = $dbCourseName; 
            $dataArray[$dbCourseId]['CourseNo'] = $dbCourseNo; 
            $dataArray[$dbCourseId]['Modules'][$dbModuleId]['ModuleName'] = $dbModuleName; 
            $dataArray[$dbCourseId]['Modules'][$dbModuleId]['ModuleNo'] = $dbModuleNo; 

            // session data
            $_SESSION['idcourse'] = $dbCourseNo;
            $_SESSION['namecourse'] = $dbCourseName;
            $_SESSION['idmodule'] = $dbModuleNo;
            $_SESSION['namemodule'] = $dbModuleName;

            }

        foreach ($dataArray as $foundCourse => $courseData) {

            $output = ""; 

            $output .= "<p><strong>Course:</strong> " . $courseData['CourseNo'] .  " - "  . $courseData['CourseName'] . "</p>";

            $moduleHTML = ""; 
            $moduleHTML .= '<select name="module" id="modulesDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
            $moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;      
            foreach ($courseData['Modules'] as $moduleId => $moduleData) {        

                $moduleHTML .= "<option value='$moduleId'>" . $moduleData['ModuleNo'] . " - " . $moduleData['ModuleName'] ."</option>".PHP_EOL;        
            } 
        }
    $moduleHTML .= '</select>';

    echo $output;

?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Course: <?php echo $moduleHTML; ?>
                <input id="courseSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

So lets say I select the Course `INFO101 - Information Communication Technology` in the "Course" drop down menu, it displays the following modules in the Module drop down menu below which corresponds with that course:

```
CHI2520 - Advanced Web Programming
CHI2220 - Systems Strategy
CHI2350 - Interactive Systems
```

Now this is the problem I have. If I select the module `CHI2520 - Advanced Web Programming` and then access the page below, it displays this module instead `CHI2350 - Interactive Systems`.

QandATable.php:

```
    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['idmodule'])) {

        $_SESSION['idmodule'] = $_POST['idmodule'];

    }

    if (isset($_POST['namemodule'])) {

        $_SESSION['namemodule'] = $_POST['namemodule'];

    }

if (isset($_POST['idcourse'])) {

$_SESSION['idcourse'] = $_POST['idcourse'];

}

if (isset($_POST['namecourse'])) {

$_SESSION['namecourse'] = $_POST['namecourse'];

}


    $outputDetails = "";
    $outputDetails .= "
    <table id='sessionDetails' border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Course:</th> 
    <th>{$_SESSION['idcourse']}  {$_SESSION['namecourse']}</th>
    </tr>
<tr>
<th>Module:</th> 
<th>{$_SESSION['idmodule']}  {$_SESSION['namemodule']}</th>
</tr>
    </table>
    ";

    echo $outputDetails;

    ?>
```

My question is that why does it display the wrong module number and name in the other page? Both page does include `session_start();`

Below is form which navigates to QandATable.php:

```
<form action="QandATable.php" method="post" id="sessionForm">
            <table><tr><th>6: Module:</th>
            <td><?php echo $moduleHTML; ?></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <p><input class="questionBtn" type="submit" value="Prepare Questions" name="prequestion" /></p>   


        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

set the select to autocomplete="off" and it should fix this behavior. The browser's autocomplete is trying to keep things how they were for the user, against your telling it to do otherwise. It drove me plenty crazy.

```
<select autocomplete="off" name="courses" id="coursesDrop">
```

Comment: So can I ask why it keeps choosing the module it keeps displaying in the next page? Is there a certain reason why this behaviour occurs if you know what I mean? Why does it not not display the other modules out of the three?

Comment: I'm guessing it is picking what you have chosen in the past at some point, I can't say exactly why. I hope setting that attribute helps.

Comment: I will giveit a go, but can you see if I have done something wrong with my $_SESSION variables? All I want to do is display `$dbModuleNo and $dbModuleName` in the session variables and then use them to be displayed in the next page

Comment: I tried the autocomplete="off" in both the course and module select tags but no change. Like I said in my question, it displays the correct course details chosen but it displays the incorrect module details chosen